# How to create a rank matrix with column names instead of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to Python.
I have a data frame like the following

```
       book 1      book 2     book 3  
user 1  0.05       0.47       0.09
user 2  0.3        0.01       0.35
```

I want it to be ranked based on the values(descending order) and the output to be the following:

```
        Rank 1      Rank 2      Rank 3 
user1   book 2      book 3      book 1
user2   book 3      book 1      book 2
```

[this is how the matrix looks in real task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiHpP.jpg)

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have tried :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.

```
pandas.DataFrame([df.columns[x] for x in np.argsort(-df.values)], 
                 index=df.index, 
                 columns=['rank' + str(i + 1) for i in range(df.shape[1])])

       rank1  rank2
user1  book2  book1
user2  book1  book2
```

Comment: this approach sorts values in the first row, and then does not sort/rank values for other rows

Comment: @user9436638 That is incorrect. `np.argsort` 'axis' argument defaults to -1, meaning it performs argsort along each item of the final axis. Note this is different from the `pandas.Series.argsort` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_cols = {'book %i' % i: 'Rank %i' % i for i in range(1, df.shape[1]+1)}
df.apply(lambda s: s.index[s.argsort()][::-1], axis=1).rename(new_cols, axis=1)
```

returns

```
        Rank 1  Rank 2  Rank 3
user 1  book 2  book 3  book 1
user 2  book 3  book 1  book 2
```

Comment: @user9436638 Just updated for your new example. What isn't working?

Comment: no(( it just sorts the first row and copies its values to the remaining rows

Comment: @user9436638 Ah... what's the output for the example that you gave? I'm getting exactly the desired output.

Comment: np.argsort defaults to axis=-1, which means the default behavior is to argsort along the final axis. `axis=1` is not needed if using `np.argsort`.

Comment: @ely The `axis=1` kwargs is to `.apply` not `.argsort`. Additionally `.argsort` is applied to a Series in this example so no need to specify `axis`.

Comment: Correct -- what I mean is that the whole operation of `apply` followed by Series-wise individual uses of `argsort` can all be replaced by a single (natively vectorized) call to `np.argsort`. In other words, it is one of those situations where `apply` with a lambda is entirely obviated by a pre-existing built-in function.

Comment: @ely Agreed :)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply:

```
(
     df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().index[::-1], axis=1)
     .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('book','Rank'))
)
Out[9]: 
        Rank 1  Rank 2
user 1  book 2  book 1
user 2  book 1  book 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

Notice: as @ely mentioned in comment, `axis=1` is not necessary

```
df = pd.DataFrame((-df.values).argsort() + 1, index=df.index)
#same as
#df = pd.DataFrame((-df.values).argsort(axis=1) + 1, index=df.index)
print (df)
        0  1  2
user 1  2  3  1
user 2  3  1  2
```

Change columns names and values in `DataFrame`:

```
df.columns = ['Rank {}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]
df = 'book ' + df.astype(str)
print (df)
        Rank 1  Rank 2  Rank 3
user 1  book 2  book 3  book 1
user 2  book 3  book 1  book 2
```

Comment: `np.argsort` documentation says that axis defaults to -1, and that argsort is performed along the final axis by default. `axis=1` is not needed, with `np.argsort` at least.